# Jensen's Inequality, Landau-Notation

Tags: numerical-methods

I would love to know how to show the following:

$n!n^{s} = o(n^n)$ fo $n \rightarrow \infty, s \geq 0$

As for a hint, I know that $\sum_{k=1}^n \log k \leq n* \log (\frac{n+1}{2})^{n}$ can be used, but haven't really come far.

Answer (score 2):

By [Stirling's approximation formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation):
$$n!\sim_{+\infty}\sqrt{2\pi n}\left(\frac{n}{e}\right)^n,$$

we have
$$\frac{n!n^s}{n^n}\sim\sqrt{2\pi n}e^{-n}n^{s}\to_{n\to\infty}0,$$
so we have the result.

Comment: thank you, still I was wondering if the implication of Jensen is also a possibility to prove the "equality"

Answer (score 1):

For every $1\leq k<n+s$ we have
$$n!=1\cdots k \cdots n \leq k^k n^{n-k}.$$
For simplicity assume $n$ is even, and let $k=n/2$. Thus
$$
n!\leq \left(\frac{n}{2}\right)^{n/2}\cdot n^{n/2}= \frac{n^n}{2^{n/2}}. 
$$
So 
$$
n!n^s\leq n^n\frac{n^s}{2^{n/2}} = o(n^n),
$$
since $\lim \frac{n^s}{2^{n/2}}=0$.

Comment: thanks, yet I did not understand how you came up with $\left(\frac{n}{2}\right)^{n/2}\cdot n^{n/2}$..?

Comment: I just putted k=n/2 in the above formula. Then n-k=n/2 too.